# Start over and upgrade the app that is in the store (New project - CoreData)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have one app in the store with CoreData model, and i want change entirely the app (remove some garbage, organize, new CoreData model... etc).

**So i thinking start over and create new project**, what will happen when i try to upgrade the old app that is in the store to this new one? (i'm concerned about CoreData)

thanks a lot

Comment: Core Data has full support for both automatic and custom migration. The custom migration path is more difficult, but it's definitely possible to migrate stuff even if your entire model has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a core data model even slightly, you need to migrate data to the new model:

> You can only open a Core Data store using the managed object model used to create it. Changing a model will therefore make it incompatible with (and so unable to open) the stores it previously created. If you change your model, you therefore need to change the data in existing stores to new version—changing the store format is known as migration.

That's from Apple's docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

So if you want users to have their old data in your new version you're essentially going to have to replicate the old core data model in order to extract and migrate the data to your new model. For any release subsequent to that one, of course, you can get rid of the old model.

Comment: Thanks! and if i don't want users to have their old data? just like new app without anything stored...i need to do exactly the same?

Comment: Well if you don't care about the core data store, then of course you can trash it. There's no need to migrate data if you're not going to do anything with it.